# Overfull hbox with a minipage inside a tabular environment

Tags: tables, minipage

I have the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
test text 1
    &   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        test text 2
        \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces something that looks like

[image]

The issue is that this produces a warning saying "Overfull \hbox". What's going on here? What's the best way to fix it?

**ASIDE**: I have found that if I use a `tabularx` environment, as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|X}
test text 1
    &   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        test text 2
        \end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

then the warning goes away, however I'm not sure why, or if this is the proper solution.

Comment: The width of the `minipage` is determined by the `linewidth`. This is in the first table equal to the text width, so the table is wider than the text (4x `\tabcolsep` + `first column width` + `\textwidth`). In the second table equal it is equal to the the width of column X, so the table does not exceed the prescribed width.

Comment: @Zarko what width should I use instead of `\linewidth`?

Comment: Why you need `minipage` in table? Instead it you can use `p(<width>)` or `X` column type. It is seems that later is what you after. I can't say more since I don't know context of your table. Use of `\linewidth` has may benefits  because it is not determined in advance but by the width of environment where is used. In your case it is in the second table determined by width of `X` column, and in the first table by text width since columns `c`, `l` and `r` haven't prescribed widths and consequently in time of the use of `minipage` the `\textwidth` is in only known width to the `linewidth`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the `\linewidth` is not prescribed in advance but is always automatically adopted to the width of environment, where is used.  For example, in text body `linewidth` is equal to `\textwidth`, in column of multi column document is equal to `\columnwidth`, in some list (itemize, for example) is equal to widths of items. So, in many time its features is very desirably.

In your examples this means, that when is used in `X` column it has width of column minus two `\tabcolsep`, at use in the `p{<column width>}` has width of `<column width>` but when is used in columns `c`, `l` or `r`, which not has prescribed widths (their width is equal of width of their contents) the last known width in table is `\textwidth` so the width of minipage in the first example is equal to `\textwidth`.

What width you should use instead of `linewidth`? Depends, of your needs which is unknown to us. In the most cases you not need `minipage` in table but just appropriate column type, for example `p{<desired width>}` where you determine your width (for example 12em) or `X` which width is calculated by LaTeX from width of table.

More about tables you can find in the [Wiki: tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need something like this:
[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
        test text 1     &       \lipsum[1][1-3]\\
        test text 2     &       \lipsum[2][1-3]\\
        test text 3     &       \lipsum[3][1-3]\\           
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```